# Best jQuery Status Message Plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, user-interface

What is the best jQuery status message plugin?

I like [jGrowl](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jgrowl) and [Purr](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/purr), but jGrowl doesn't have the feature to remain sticky (not close automatially) and Purr doesn't seem to work right in IE 6.

I would like to show messages like... the site is about to go down for maintenance, your such and such job has completed, and stuff like that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

jGrowl does look to have sticky - see sample 2 in the demo page:

https://github.com/stanlemon/jGrowl

...ah - or did you mean after the page has reloaded?

I would then handle this on the server side - i.e. include a sitedown.js that triggers the growl notice each time any page is visited.

Comment: nice. it is really working well. except that i need to call it with out using a class and to close it just like close(). anyway i modified the js code to include my needs. good example.

Comment: jGrowl is an easy to use script but it doesn't have top-full-width or bottom-full-width option.

Answer (score 19):

A few options...

- [Humanized Messages](http://code.google.com/p/humanmsg/) (<strike>[demo](http://binarybonsai.com/misc/humanmsg/)</strike>, 3 KB) looks very cool, and has a nice history rollout
- [Pines Notify](http://sciactive.github.io/pnotify/) (13 KB) is extremely customizable and supports jQuery UI themes
- [jGrowl](https://github.com/stanlemon/jGrowl) (6 KB) does actually have a sticky option - use { sticky: true }

Answer (score 9):

I really like this humanmessage plugin. You can customize it to hang around longer and change the appearance, etc --

http://code.google.com/p/humanmsg/

Comment: i like this too. really nice. but there haven't been a need now. so i have book marked this. nice.

Answer (score 6):

In order of my preference

- Noty http://needim.github.com/noty/ 6kb | Requires jQuery | Github
- Humane-JS https://github.com/wavded/humane-js  | [Demo](http://wavded.github.com/humane-js/) | GitHub
- JQuery UI Growl Notification  http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/a-jquery-ui-growl-ubuntu-notification-widget/
- Pines Notify http://pinesframework.org/pnotify/  15KB | SourceForge-Mercurial
- SmokeJS https://github.com/jyoungblood/smoke.js  | Github
- js Message http://dhtmlx.github.com/message/    4KB | MIT | GIthub

Answer (score 5):

We have started using http://boedesign.com/demos/gritter/ and have to say it accomplishes the osx growl feel better than the others listed out of the box.

Comment: agreed, it's easy to use and (so far) easy to style.  Be warned, the rails gem at this writing isn't 3.1-friendly.

Answer (score 3):

We found following simple code from west-wind very helpful in our project.

http://www.beyondweblogs.com/post/Display-Fancy-Status-Message-using-JQuery.aspx

Answer (score 2):

- I used jQuery *Noty* plugin before, but after v2 it doesn't use css file. You should include too much js file if you use different options.
- Toastr is a good alternative. Usage is simple and it is actively developed project.
  It has top-full-width and bottom-full-width option without using any other js file.

  Repo: https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr
  Demos: http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/
- Pnotify is very detailed and easy to use plugin. It has too many options that looks fun and has a very helpful demo page.

  Repo: https://github.com/sciactive/pnotify
  Demos: http://pinesframework.org/pnotify/#demos-simple

Answer (score 1):

Here's an Outlook Popup style notification jQuery widget:

> - [jQuery.UI Messenger\Outlook like message notification Widget](http://mosesofegypt.net/post/2008/07/16/jQueryui-Messenger-Outlook-like-message-notification-Widget.aspx)
>
> > - [Demo](http://mosesofegypt.net/samples00/jQueryNotificationMessage/)

Comment: both the demos at this date showing SERVER ERROR. could you add the current links so that users would be benefited.

Comment: Thanks, Jayapal. The demo download seems to be a working alternative: http://mosesofegypt.net/file.axd?file=jQueryNotificationMessage.zip

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty nice humanized message one here: http://www.websanova.com/plugins/humanmsg/jquery#websanova

Comment: Including an external reference to a well documented source is appreciated here on Stack Overflow but it is important to include in your answer the most important/relevant snippets from the external source and give context as to how the answer the question because if that link goes dead (server goes down, etc), then your answer becomes useless.